# Using Combo box for foreign key in MVC 6 razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, combobox

I have inherited LIMISAppUser from IdentityUser with MVC 6.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using WebPortal.Models;

namespace WebPortal.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public class LIMISAppUser : IdentityUser
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide first name")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longetr than 20 letters")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide last name")]
        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longetr than 20 letters")]
        public string LastName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Must provide a parent id to continue. Please contact your company/organisation to get parents id.")]
        [Display(Name ="Your Organisation's ID")]
        public int OrgId { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Must inform your relationship with the company")]
        //[Display(Name = "Relationship with the Organization")]
        //public iStarEntity RelationWithOrg { get; set; }
        
        //[Required(ErrorMessage ="Must mention relation with organization")]
        //[Display(Name = "Relationship with the Organization")]
        //public int RelationWithOrg { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Must choose a relation")]
        //[Display(Name = "Relationship with the Organization")]
        public int RelWithOrg { get; set; }
        public iStarEntity Entity { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Must provide Id Number provided to you by your organisation")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name ="Your personal ID in the organization")]
        public string IdNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;


        [Display(Name ="Profile Picture")]
        public byte[] ProfilePic { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get { return (FirstName + " " + LastName); } }
    }
}
```

I have updated Register.cshtml input model with the same. now i want to use a dropdown combo box to get the values for RelWithOrg property from iStarEntity model.

Can anyone please guide me that how can i do this. I gave tried @Html.DropDownListFor() but i do noy know where to get its parametrs from.

Comment: `get the values for RelWithOrg property from iStarEntity model`RelWithOrg  is int type data,dropdown needs a list,what model you passed to the view which needs a dropdown?

Comment: The model is iStarEntity. I want that all the entries from table iStarEntity appear in a combo box. the value of that combo box will be the ID of iStarEntity table.

Comment: This is code from Register.cshtml view for Register Page.... I need help in converting this <input> to combo box             <div class="form-floating mt-2">
                <input asp-for="Input.RelWithOrg" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" aria-required="true" />
                <label asp-for="Input.RelWithOrg"></label>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.RelWithOrg" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>